# Stop regex at \n

Tags: regex, notepad++, pcre

I need to add bbcode tags to URLs that doesn't have any tags with them. I'm currently using regex to find them, but I'm having problems with some cases.
Here are the cases I'm testing on:

```
www.example.com                                                 //OK
http://example.com                                              //OK
http://www.example.com                                          //OK
http://www.example.com/test/                                    //OK
http://www.example.com/test/image.jpg                           //OK
www.example.com\nSome random text                               //not working, should find www.example.com only
Some random text\nhttp://www.example.com                        //OK
http://example.com\nSome random text                            //not working, should find http://example.com only
http://www.example.com\nSome random text                        //not working, should find http://www.example.com only
Some random text\nhttp://www.example.com\nSome random text      //not working, should find http://www.example.com only
http://www.example.com\nhttp://www.example.com/test/image.jpg\n //not working should find both http://www.example.com and http://www.example.com/test/image.jpg
[IMG]http://www.example.com/test/image.jpg[/IMG]                //OK
[URL]http://www.example.com[/URL]                               //OK
[url=http://www.example.com]Domain[/url]                        //OK
[url=http://www.example.com]http://www.example.com[/url]        //OK
```

I'm using Notepad++ to test and the regex is:

```
(?:(?<!(\[\/url\]|\[\/url=)))(((https?|ftps?|ircs?):\/\/\S+)|(www\.\S+))(?:(?<![[:punct:]])|(?<=\/))(\s|\.?$)
```

So I guess the biggest issue I have is that regex doesn't stop at \n-character.

Comment: Try not making it multiline

Comment: So `\n` here is a string literal and not a newline character?

Comment: Yes it's literal string I think. The text I'm trying to change is from SQL dump.

Comment: I would have thought replacing the `\S+` by `(?:\S(?<!\\n))+` would work, but that seems to break the regex somehow.

Comment: @revo Thanks, that almost works! But when text to search is like this `[url=http://www.example.com]Example Address[/url]` it fails and matches too much. I actually forgot to add that as a test case.

Comment: @revo Also your regex doesn't seem to capture the URL as a group so I could replace it with proper tags.

Comment: What is your replacement string?

Comment: @revo Replacement string will be [URL]matched_url[/URL]

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/ToyrYf/1